# Cloned Windows 10 into SSD on a Lenovo ThinkPad T460, now doesn't boot in Dell Vostro 3500

Tags: windows-10, ssd, mbr, clone, gpt

I have cloned Windows 10 from a Lenovo ThinkPad T460 original hard drive into an SSD and it works just fine. But now, the ThinkPad got broken, and I want to connect this SSD to my spare computer: a Dell Vostro 3500. The BIOS detects it, but doesn't boot Windows. The black screen is showing up and nothing. By the way, SSD is a GPT drive. I think the problem is that the Dell doesn't boot this GPT drive and needs an MBR.

How can I get my Dell to boot Windows from my SSD?

Comment: Well I'd never expect that to work anyway, and the key will likely be invalid. A reinstall of windows is your best bet.

Comment: @djsmiley2k thanks for advice, i thought the same thing, but still had some hope in this situation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options spring to mind:

**1** - There are methods like [this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fdisk#Convert_between_MBR_and_GPT) that can convert GPT disk layouts to MBR without data loss. Of course, there is a risk of losing the data.

**2** - You can use a live disk of any Linux distribution that uses GRUB and then [manually boot the partition from GRUB's command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259069/how-to-start-a-windows-partition-from-the-grub-command-line-please-help) if there is a boot record present in the Windows partition. Once Windows has booted you can then reinstall the boot loader from there.

Of course, there may be other ways to achieve what you want. In any case, a backup of the whole disk is always recommendable before trying anything.

Additionally, as pointed out in the comments, due to the different hardware Windows may not be functioning normal on the other computer and a fresh installation would indeed be the cleanest way. Just be sure to copy any important data to another disk using a live disk before that ;)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, the GRUB method looks promising, but i think a clean install is unavoidable in this case..